# How to edit the footer links in magento 2

Tags: footer, magento-2.0.2

I want to edit the Footer links in Magento 2. I have installed magento 2.0.2(with sample data). At backend, when I go to `content/blocks` I don't see any blocks there (the page is empty with no blocks). But when I open the frontend , footer links are available.I don't know from which file are they coming from.
Someone please guide me with explanation to edit and rearrange the footer links.

Comment: how to add several links in a row? I would like add 4 url link pages <referenceBlock name="footer_links"> <referenceBlock name="privacy-policy-link" remove="true" /> <referenceBlock name="search-term-popular-link" remove="true" /> <referenceBlock name="contact-us-link" remove="true" /> <referenceBlock name="catalog-search-advanced-link" remove="true" /> <referenceBlock name="sales-guest-form-link" remove="true" /> <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="test"> <arguments> <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">test</argument> <argument name="pat

Answer (score 6):

All footer links are coming from `default.xml` files.

```
Privacy and cookie policy link: vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
Search Terms link: vendor/vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
Contact us link: vendor/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
Order and Returns link: vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
Advanced search link: vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

Here Sample code for rearrange footer links.

```
Contact Us
Privacy and Cookie Policy
Advanced Search
Orders and Returns
Search Terms
```

For rearrange position you have to do code below inside theme `default.xml` file.

```
 <referenceBlock name="footer_links">            
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="privacy-policy-link" after="contact-us-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Privacy and Cookie Policy</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
             <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="catalog/seo/search_terms" name="search-term-popular-link" after="sales-guest-form-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Search Terms</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">search/term/popular</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="contact/contact/enabled" name="contact-us-link" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Us</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">contact</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
             <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Guest\Link" name="sales-guest-form-link" after="catalog-search-advanced-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Orders and Returns</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/guest/form</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
             <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="catalog-search-advanced-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Advanced Search</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">catalogsearch/advanced</argument>
                    <argument name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="data-action" xsi:type="string">advanced-search</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

You can do as per your requirement using **before or after** method and change position.

Comment: Should I put the above code in `default.xml` file of `app/design/frontend/<my_package>/<my_theme>/Magento_theme/layout`  by inheriting it from `vendor`?

Comment: yes you have to put inside theme default.xml file and its working as per your requirement then accept answer.

Comment: NO it is not changing

Comment: Have you clear cache?

Comment: yes i cleared the cache

Comment: plz show your default.xml file with your theme path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38771/discussion-between-ramya-and-rakesh).

Answer (score 1):

This footer links are coming from different module layout.
Like:

```
Privacy-cookie: magento2/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
Search Terms : magento2/vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
Contact: magento2/magento/module-contact/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
Advance search: magento2/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
Order Returns: magento2/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

**Hope you will understand now! Happy learning**

Comment: How to rearrange the order of these  links?

Answer (score 0):

Footer links are found in particular module `defualt.xml` under `<referenceBlock name="footer_links">` tag.

For Example for the Privacy and Cookie Policy, You can change it from -  `magento2/vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

Comment: when I edit my layout file by overriding them in my theme. The changes are not applied. But when I edit them inside the `vendor/Magento/modules/view/frontend/layout` changes are eshtablished.

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
    <referenceBlock name="privacy-policy-link" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="search-term-popular-link" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="contact-us-link" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog-search-advanced-link" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="sales-guest-form-link" remove="true" />

    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="test">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">test</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">test</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```